# Creating drop downs from a unordered list

Tags: jquery

There is a unordered list from which I want to create drop downs using jquery.
Basically I want to create six drop downs like this:

productType - ABC, XYZ

reportNames - Report1, Report2

startDate - 2010, 2011

startMonth - May, June

endDate - 2010, 2011

endMonth - May, June

And clicking on these drop down elements will update the rest of the drop downs. One guy from stackoverflow helped me to create these drop downs out of a JSON object. But now I want to have the same thing from the UL and LIs. Please help me out!!

Here is the demo of the one which is created from JSON - http://jsfiddle.net/Lnv9d/7/

And here is the unordered list -

```
  <html>

<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=us-ascii">
    <style>
        <!-- .decisionTree {
            display:none
        }
        -->
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <ul class="decisionTree productType">
        <li><span>ABC</span>

            <ul class="reportType">
                <li><span>Report 1</span>

                    <ul class="reportYearStart">
                        <li><span>2011</span>

                            <ul class="reportMonthStart">
                                <li><span>July</span> 
                                </li>
                                <li><span>June</span> 
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li><span>2010</span>

                            <ul class="reportMonthStart">
                                <li><span>December</span> 
                                </li>
                                <li><span>November</span> 
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                    <ul class="reportYear">
                        <li><span>2011</span>

                            <ul class="reportMonth">
                                <li><span>July</span> 
                                </li>
                                <li><span>June</span> 
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li><span>2010</span>

                            <ul class="reportMonth">
                                <li><span>December</span> 
                                </li>
                                <li><span>November</span> 
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><span>Report 2</span>

                    <ul class="reportYearStart">
                        <li><span>2011</span>

                            <ul class="reportMonthStart">
                                <li><span>July</span> 
                                </li>
                                <li><span>June</span> 
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li><span>2010</span>

                            <ul class="reportMonthStart">
                                <li><span>October</span> 
                                </li>
                                <li><span>September</span> 
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                    <ul class="reportYear">
                        <li><span>2011</span>

                            <ul class="reportMonth">
                                <li><span>April</span> 
                                </li>
                                <li><span>March</span> 
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li><span>2010</span>

                            <ul class="reportMonth">
                                <li><span>August</span> 
                                </li>
                                <li><span>July</span> 
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><span>XYZ</span>

            <ul class="reportType">
                <li><span>Report 3</span>

                    <ul class="reportYearStart">
                        <li><span>2020</span>

                            <ul class="reportMonthStart">
                                <li><span>July</span> 
                                </li>
                                <li><span>June</span> 
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li><span>2021</span>

                            <ul class="reportMonthStart">
                                <li><span>December</span> 
                                </li>
                                <li><span>November</span> 
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                    <ul class="reportYear">
                        <li><span>2022</span>

                            <ul class="reportMonth">
                                <li><span>July</span> 
                                </li>
                                <li><span>June</span> 
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li><span>2023</span>

                            <ul class="reportMonth">
                                <li><span>December</span> 
                                </li>
                                <li><span>November</span> 
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><span>Report 4</span>

                    <ul class="reportYearStart">
                        <li><span>2024</span>

                            <ul class="reportMonthStart">
                                <li><span>July</span> 
                                </li>
                                <li><span>June</span> 
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li><span>2025</span>

                            <ul class="reportMonthStart">
                                <li><span>October</span> 
                                </li>
                                <li><span>September</span> 
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                    <ul class="reportYear">
                        <li><span>2026</span>

                            <ul class="reportMonth">
                                <li><span>April</span> 
                                </li>
                                <li><span>March</span> 
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li><span>2027</span>

                            <ul class="reportMonth">
                                <li><span>August</span> 
                                </li>
                                <li><span>July</span> 
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</body>
```

Comment: perfect scenario for a jquery plugin :)

Comment: It's working fine now. Here is the working example: http://jsfiddle.net/tK6Nx/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did three of the selects, you should have an idea from there on:

You should mainly use direct children selectors `$("parent > children")`
 to select the direct li's and spans. And since none of this stuff has id's, you will need the `:contains` selector to find spans with certain text.

```
$("#root > li > span").each(function(){
    $("#productType").append("<option value='" + $(this).text() + "'>" + $(this).text() + "</option>");
});

$("#productType").on("change",function(){
    var selected = $(this).val(); //selected value
    $("#reportName").empty(); //clears reports
    $("#reportName").append("<option value='-1'>Select</option>"); //adds an empty item

    //selector: selects from the li's with the text (ABC, or XYZ), - select its span children
    $("li:contains('" + selected + "') > ul > li > span").each(function()
    {
        $("#reportName").append("<option value='" + $(this).text() + "'>" + $(this).text() + "</option>");
    });
});

$("#reportName").on("change",function(){
    var selected = $(this).val(); //selected value
    $("#startDate").empty(); //clears reports
    $("#startDate").append("<option value='-1'>Select</option>"); //adds an empty item

    //selector: selects from the li's with the text, - select its span children
    $(".reportType > li:contains('" + selected + "') > ul > li > span").each(function()
    {
        $("#startDate").append("<option value='" + $(this).text() + "'>" + $(this).text() + "</option>");
    });
});
```

give your main ul an id:

```
<ul id="root" class="decisionTree productType">
```

Here it is working: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hescano/8ytzE/)

Notice that after the second select I use the class selector (like .reportType). You can start using those to better select your elements.

Comment: thanks a lot. I want to show the drop downs for ABC first. There will no 'Select' option in any of the drop downs. Can it be achieved quickly. Also it would be of great help if you could create the drop downs for Start date/Start Month and End date/End Month as well.

Comment: Sorry, I cannot do that for you. I have given you enough examples that you can take it from there. If you cannot figure out from that code (even with the provided comments) how to remove the 'Select', I would strongly recommend that you read a good jQuery book.

Comment: Actually I can remove the select but want to populate options for other drop downs from the parent element which is 'ABC' when the page loads. Also please let me know how I can create drop downs for Start date/Start Month and End date/End.

Answer (score 0):

Essentially you need to walk the DOM tree and populate a series of arrays with your data; you can then interact with it much the same as you did with the data coming from JSON. The exact format and style I will leave up to you, but the method goes as follows.

Lets say you had data like so:

```
<ul>
    <li>Item 1</li>
    <li>Item 2</li>
    <li>Item 3</li>
    <li>Item 4</li>
</ul>
```

You would enumerate that into a javascript array by doing the following:

```
var items = [];

$('ul > li').each(function() {
    items.push($(this).text());
});
```

If you had mixed items you wanted to separate you could do something like:

```
<ul>
    <li class='a1'>Item 1</li>
    <li class='a2'>Item 2</li>
    <li class='a1'>Item 3</li>
    <li class='a2'>Item 4</li>
</ul>
```

And the javascript:

```
var a1items = [],
    a2items = [];

$('ul > li').each(function() {
    a1items .push($('.a1', $(this)).text());
    a2items .push($('.a2', $(this)).text());
});
```

By mixing and matching those snippets you should be able to cobble together the arrays to make your dropdowns. If you need further help please post a comment and I will try and assist further.

Comment: If possible could you please create a fiddle for this. No need to do it fully but if could show me the process then that would be great

Comment: @HanletEscaño Thank you so much!! I really appreciate your effort.